# Error mocking concrete class with PHP mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery

The class under test is as follows:

```
class ElasticSearchInstaller
{
    /**
     * Version of ElasticSearch 
     *
     * @var \ElasticSearch\Requierments
     */
    protected $requirements;        

    /**
     * Object Constructor.
     * 
     * @param Requierments $requirements 
     */
    public function __construct(Requirements $requirements)
    {
        $this->requirements = $requirements;
    }

    /**
     * Set requirements
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canInstall() 
    {
        return ($this->isInstalled() && $this->requirements->checkRequirements());
    }   
}
```

The test looks as follows:

```
class ElasticSearchInstallerTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test **/
    public function it_can_check_if_its_installable()
    {
        $requirements = m::mock('alias:ElasticSearch\Requirements');

        $requirements->shouldReceive('checkRequirements')->once()->andReturn(true); 

        $installer = new ElasticSearchInstaller($requirements);

        $this->assertInternalType('bool', $installer->canInstall());
    }    
}
```

Although for some reason it does not pass, as the mock says `checkRequirements()` is not being called and expects to be called once.

```
1) ElasticSearchInstallerTest::it_can_check_if_its_installable
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method checkRequirements() from App\ElasticSearch\Requirements should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

**EDIT**
The problem was, within `canInstall()` for some reason if `$this->isInstalled()` is called before `$this->requirements->checkRequirements()` such as in the code above. It errors. if its swapped to:

```
public function canInstall() 
{
    return ($this->requirements->checkRequirements() && $this->isInstalled() );
}
```

...it passes! wtf?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to 'alias:' is, or really have that test, as you are   really just checking that a mock can return a boolean. `canInstall` is a too-simple-to-fail proxy to `Requirements`.

Comment: There will be many other requirements and conditions in canInstall i just simplified it for the example.

Comment: I did run much the same code (directly under PHPUnit_Framework_Testcase fine (with, and without the alias).  but I appreciate that 'works for me' doesn't help much.  Are you running at `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ?

Comment: Yes, `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is on. I can't see anything else. Its running under Lumen (laravel).

Comment: I have worked it out... i will post the edit.

Comment: Take a look at that @Alister Bulman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that such boolean conditions can be shortcut -if the first part of an `&&` (and) condition is FALSE, the whoe condition itself cannot become true, and so the rest of the parts of the conditional is skipped. The function call was skipped, hence, run 0 times.

Since, in that specific test, you only only currently testing the condition as a whole, you can mock the rest of the `ElasticSearchInstaller` and do much the same:

```
$searchInstaller->shouldReceive('isInstalled')->andReturn(true);
```

The mock would fall back to use the original canInstall(), and so run the condition. It's still almost a too-simple-to-fail case though - I'd concentrate elsewhere for testing.

Comment: of course! face-slap... `isInstalled()` contains a native function... how does one mock that / test that ?